# How to activate "go to definition" in Eclipse for inherited class property

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc

I have a base class (lets call it A) and I have inheriting Class (lets call it AA).
In a different abstract class I have:

```
abstract class DifferentClass{
 /**
  *@var A
  */
 protected MyA;
}
```

In a more different class:

```
class MoreDifferent extends DifferentClass{
  public function __construct(){
    $this->MyA = new AA;
  }
}
```

My problem is when I ctrl+left click on `MyA` in the inheriting class, it will take me to the original class A file. I would like it to take me to the `AA` file.
What is the PHPdoc way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the only "phpdoc" thing you've done is show that the protected MyA property is of type "A".

The phpdoc definitions are *not* going to pick up *anything* from the " = new AA" code line itself.

I think you could potentially locally sort-of-override this behavior by making an explicit relisting of "protected MyA" in your MoreDifferent class, and put a docblock there that shows "@var AA".  I don't really see any other option to get the behavior you're after.